# Connect IRF520 MOSFET Driver to a Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, driver

I'm trying to find a way to connect a DC motor to a IRF520 MOSFET Driver to a Raspberry Pi 2 to then to control the DC motor. I'm new to electronics and I haven't found any clear solutions.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Which part is causing the problem?  It would be a courtesy if you gave links to the items you are using rather than expecting people to search.

Comment: here is driver module http://www.gearbest.com/sensors/pp_226185.html

Comment: It's best if you edit your question and add useful information there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not really what I would call a motor driver board.

For low current operation I'd be looking at L298N, or L293D, or L9110S based boards.  They let you drive a pair of motors forwards and backwards.

The IRF520 does have the advantage of providing more power which may be why you want to use it.

Anyhow connect V+ and V- to your DC motor (if the motor doesn't spin in the direction you want you will need to swap the leads).

Connect VIN to the motor power supply +ve.  Connect GND to the motor power supply -ve.

Connect VCC to a Pi 3V3 pin (pins 1 or 17).  Connect GND to a Pi ground (say pin 6) and connect STG to a Pi GPIO (say 4 on pin 7).

To start the motor (full speed) set GPIO 4 high.  To stop the motor set GPIO 4 low.  To control the motor speed send PWM pulses on GPIO 4.

A PWM pulse just means switch the GPIO rapidly on and off, varying the ratio of on to off to control the speed.